# Android - native global object destructor never called

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I load a shared library, with the classic System.loadLibrary() method, from a static java block. The library has global object allocated statically:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo()
   {
   }

   ~Foo()
   {
      logtofile( "Foo::~Foo() called" );
   }
}


Foo dummy;
```

The global function logtofile writes a log file on the sdcard. While the constructor gets called when the library is loaded, it seems to me that the destructor is never called. I expected that between two constructors calls there should be a destructor call. So the question is: when the Foo destructor gets called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android never unloads native libraries; usually the app process dies spontaneously when the system decides that it needs its resources - and it does an equivalent of `kill -9`, never calling destructors or Java `finalize()`.